# Método isSelected() de la clase JCheckbox no funciona

Tags: java, eclipse, java-swing

El método isSelected() no lee la selección y siempre devuelve false. Este es mi codigo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.opencsv.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Formulario extends JFrame implements ActionListener, 
ChangeListener{
private JCheckBox check1,check2,check3;
private static String[] vec;
private JButton aplicar;

public Formulario() {
    vec=new String[3];
    vec[0]="false";
    vec[1]="false";
    vec[2]="false";
    setLayout(null);
    setTitle("LucidoS");
    setBounds(0, 0, 1370, 730);
    check1=new JCheckBox("Inglés");
    check1.setBounds(10,10,150,30);
    check1.addChangeListener(this);
    add(check1);
    check2=new JCheckBox("Francés");
    check2.setBounds(10,50,150,30);
    check2.addChangeListener(this);        
    add(check2);
    check3=new JCheckBox("Alemán");
    check3.setBounds(10,90,150,30);
    check3.addChangeListener(this);        
    add(check3);        

aplicar=new JButton("Aplicar");
aplicar.setBounds(1190,660, 85,25);
add(aplicar);
aplicar.addActionListener(this);
}
 @Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
   if (check1.isSelected()==true) 
        vec[0]="true"; else vec[0]="false";  

    if (check2.isSelected()==true) 
        vec[1]="true"; else vec[1]="false";  

    if (check3.isSelected()==true) 
         vec[2]="true"; else vec[2]="false";  

        }               
     @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
if(e.getSource()==aplicar) 
      System.exit(0);
      }    

    public static void main(String[] ar) {
    Formulario formulario1=new Formulario();
    formulario1.setVisible(true);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            System.out.println("nr: "+vec[i]);
        }    
}
```

Este código genera un cuadro de diálogo con tres checkboxes y un botón "aplicar". Guarda como String en un array la selección de cada checkbox y luego 
imprime cada selección. No importa que cuadros seleccione cuando se abre el cuadro de diálogo, siempre me imprime los 3 falsos. He visto que muchos han hecho la misma pregunta pero no he encontrado la respuesta de todas formas. Las soluciones como cambiar el método isSelected() por isChecked() (entre otros) no me han funcionado. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

---

Saludos Julio.

La razón por la que siempre obtienes `false` como salida es totalmente normal, debido a que el `for` que lee ese arreglo de `string` está justo afuera y se ejecutará después de hacer visible el `JFrame`. El valor por `default` de los `JCheckBox` al iniciar tu programa **siempre** es `false`.

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    Formulario formulario1 = new Formulario();
    formulario1.setVisible(true);

    // aquí estás indicándole a Java que obtenga los resultados, los cuáles serán siempre false
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("nr: " + vec[i]);
    }
}
```

Para lograr tu objetivo, ese `for` tiene que ser ejecutado justo cuando presiones sobre el botón `aplicar`, y eso **no** lo estás haciendo, así que agrega el `for` dentro del evento `actionPerformed` de tu botón:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == aplicar) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("nr: " + vec[i]);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

En caso de que necesites que ese arreglo sea leído fuera de tu clase `Formulario`, entonces agrégale otro `actionListener` donde instancias tu clase `Formulario`, por ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    Formulario formulario1 = new Formulario();
    formulario1.setVisible(true);

    // Así recibes los resultados del arreglo fuera de la clase Formulario y puede ser usado en este caso en el método main
    formulario1.aplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("nr: " + vec[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

O bien, en su expresión `lambda`:

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    Formulario formulario1 = new Formulario();
    formulario1.setVisible(true);

    formulario1.aplicar.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("nr: " + vec[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
   Formulario formulario1=new Formulario();
   formulario1.setVisible(true);
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        System.out.println("nr: "+vec[i]);
   }
```

Imprimes el valor del array **antes de haber seleccionado ningún checkbox**.

Todo tu `main` se ejecuta en unas fracciones de segundo y sale. El GUI se ejecuta en un `thread` separado, así que el programa continua funcionando hasta que cierras el formulario.

Puedes ver el resultado imprimiendo el array en otra parte, por ejemplo en el `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Y como debería hacer para que al clickear el botón aplicar se me guarden las selecciones de checkboxes como boolean[] o de alguna otra forma?

Comment: Ya se hace. El problema es que muestras los valores demasiado pronto, antes de que puedas hacer click. Por eso te muestra los valores por defecto.

Comment: Claro....Y como haría para retardar la ejecución o algo así xq en realidad el código que subí es solo un ejemplo, el código real es bastante más largo. Y tengo una clase que despliega el dialogo y en la clase principal hay getters para pedir los valores de los checkBoxes y cuadros numéricos (con los que tengo el mismo problema). Pero me pasa lo mismo y los getters reciben todo false

Comment: No se trata de "retardar", porque cuando tratas con interface de usuario no puedes saber cuanto tardará el usuario en hacer una acción. Tu lógica tiene que ejecutarse cuando el usuario realiza un evento que procesas en un método de un listener (p.ej. el `actionPerformed`). Busca "Programación orientada a eventos".

Comment: Gracias C. Rodriguez y SJuan. Con sus respuestas y algunas búsquedas sobre programación orientada a eventos, clases internas y demás, resolví el problema. Saludos